# Does $(10^{6n+5}-54n-46)/162$ ever be a prime for $n>0$?

Tags: prime-numbers

$(10^{6n+5}-54n-46)/162$ is prime for $n=0$, but after that I didn't find anymore prime up to $n=500$, I didn't even find a single semiprime with that form (!!). Is there prime number of such form for $n>0$ ?

Comment: Better to ask on the Math stack exchange.

Comment: I hope you were only testing even $n$, because $$\frac{10^{6n + 5} - 54n - 46}{162}$$ is even for odd $n$. Something else to take note of, if you haven't already had Mathematica spit out a few values for you: the nine digits 617283950 are repeated almost as many times as $6n + 5$ will allow. However, the three least significant digits make this problem delightfully more difficult.

Comment: They're never multiples of $11$. That's all I can tell. Hoping someone cleverer than I comes along to shed light on this.

Comment: Unless somebody finds a factorization, it is very likely that there is a prime in the series.  If we use the heuristic that $N$ is prime with probability $\frac 1{\log N}$, your number is prime with probability about $\frac 1{13.8n}$.  The sum of this diverges, so there ought to be primes there.

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question? How did you come up with this formula?

Comment: all that i trace it probably $-18(6m-53) mod 1000$ gives last three digits of $10^{12m+5}-108m-46$, assuming $n=2m$

Answer (score 5):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+617283950617283950617283950617283950617283950617281) says that $\frac{10^{6n + 5} - 54n - 46}{162}$ is a semiprime for $n=8$:

$$
617283950617283950617283950617283950617283950617281\\ =\\
3186349113015533 \times 193727657806175483856523861962184357
$$

Comment: it is also a semiprime for $n=2$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(10%5E%7B6%2A2%2B5%7D-54%2A2-46)%2F162

Comment: My feeling is that the author means "probable prime" instead of "semiprime".

Answer (score 2):

**Incomplete answer** with a factorisation (hopefully somebody could extend it) and some preliminary results ...

From:
$$10^{6n+5}-54n-46=10^{6n+5}-9\cdot6n-9\cdot5-1=10^{6n+5}-9(6n+5)-1=\\
10^{6n+5}-10-9(6n+5)+9$$
noting $p=6n+5$:
$$10^{p}-10-9(p-1)=10(10^{p-1}-1)-9(p-1)=\\ 
9\left(10\cdot(10^{p-2}+10^{p-3}+...+10+1)-(p-1)\right)=\\
9\left(10^{p-1}-1+10^{p-2}-1+...+10^2-1+10-1\right)=\\
81\left((10^{p-2}+10^{p-3}+...+10+1)+(10^{p-3}+10^{p-4}+...+10+1)+...+(10+1)+1\right)=...$$
the sum in brackets is the sum of [repunits](https://oeis.org/A002275), which appear in other interesting problems like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907229/prime-numbers-of-the-form-1-times11-times111-times1111-times-111111111/)
$$...=81\left(10^{p-2}+2\cdot 10^{p-3}+3\cdot 10^{p-4}+...+(p-2)\cdot 10+(p-1)\right)=\\
162\left(2^{6n+2}5^{6n+3}+2\cdot 2^{6n+1}5^{6n+2}+3\cdot 2^{6n}5^{6n+1}+...+(6n+3)\cdot 5+(3n+2)\right)=...$$
Obviously, for **odd $n$** the expression in brackets is divisible by $2$ and **can not be prime**. So the remaining case is $n=2k$
$$...=162\left(2^{12k+2}5^{12k+3}+2\cdot 2^{12k+1}5^{12k+2}+3\cdot 2^{12k}5^{12k+1}+...+(12k+3)\cdot 5+(6k+2)\right)$$
If $k=5t+3$ (or $n=10t+6$) then 
$$(12k+3)\cdot 5+(6k+2)=5(66t+43)$$
and the expression in brackets is divisible by $5$ and **can not be prime**.

So far, from $10$ possible cases $n=10t, n=10t+1, ...$ and $n=10t+9$, $6$ are addressed ...